# Looking for a resource about internet language

Tags: reference-request, sociolinguistics

I am looking for scholarly resources from the past decade (a little wiggle room there) that discuss the language which is used on the internet. Specifically, I would like this source to cover informal language with a focus on adolescent use of internet slang, nonstandard usage, nonstandard writing conventions (punctuation, capitalization, spelling, etc), and initialisms.

I have found Tagliamonte (2016) "So sick or so cool? The language of youth on the internet" https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/language-in-society/article/so-sick-or-so-cool-the-language-of-youth-on-the-internet/1FC2559FF83FB5832B2D150D9951E411 but would like another.

Can anyone provide a scholarly source of this type?

Comment: Here's one: https://shop.cooperhewitt.org/products/because-internet-understanding-the-new-rules-of-language

Comment: @Lambie I already have that book. I'm looking to cite the resource in AP Research (a class in which we write papers modeled off of academic journal articles). I'm looking for academic articles and not pop linguistics books.

Comment: Find the journals and you'll find the articles. But don't look at what's in the library; Gretchen's almost the only one publishing real research. It's an open field, and academic linguists mostly have ignored it.